# Could "run late" and "run out of something" be transitive verbs

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, transitivity, intransitive

I know "run late" and "run out of something" are usually intransitive verbs.

But could "run late" and "run out of something" be "transitive verbs"?

For instance:

"I am always run late by my husband"

"We are always run out of milk supply by our supplier"

Comment: in short: no. neither of those sentences are grammatical. It's also very unclear what you intend either of these sentences to mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run out of something

**We always run out** of detergent at the end of the month. No be verb.

In the morning, I'm usually running late compared to my husband.

You cannot be run late by someone. But, wait for it [joke]: You can be run out of town.

Comment: Instead of your given example i think we could also say "In the morning, I always run late" Could I say "We are/were run out of detergent/ as an adjective instead of passive voice

Comment: @BilalZafar Sure, I always run late. But run out of [something] **cannot be in the passive voice**. running late or run late are both fine.

Comment: thanks could you also help me with my other query. Could I say "We are/were run out of detergent/ as an adjective/state, instead of passive voice?

Comment: @BilalZafar I already have helped you. Don't you see that: "we were run out of x" would be passive? Passive voice does not work with the expression to run out of something. It is not an adjective. You are confusing the idea of passive and adjective in this case. The boys were tired [adjective]. The tired [adjective] boys. This is NOT that kind of thing.